# How do we know the version of a tool from command line on a remote server?

Tags: command-line, versions

How can I know the version of texmaker running on a remote server?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally, you can run `apt-cache policy <package>`, e.g.:

```
$ apt-cache policy texmaker
texmaker:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.0.2-2
  Version table:
     3.0.2-2 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/universe i386 Packages
```

Comment: You can also often read the `man`. It'll appear near the bottom. E.g. `man rsync` --> "This man page is current for version 2.6.9 of rsync."